# How to use addEventListener properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    re2.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        const re21 = document.getElementById("reso");
        re21.style.position = "absolute";
        re21.style.top = "50%";
        re21.style.left = "50%";
        console.log("Exiting Listener- mouseOver");

        re3.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            const re22 = document.getElementById("reso");
            re22.style.position = "fixed";
            re22.style.top ="0px";
            re22.style.left="0px";
            console.log("Exiting Listener- mouseout");
    
          });

      });
```

I have an html div element with id as "reso".
what i want to do is to move this element from point A to point B whenever the mouse get on to that element. How can we do this?

when we execute the above javascript code. it only moves a single turn. Then we tried with a loop for i=0 to 10 wrapped the above code in it with some console logs. all the logs were printing.
but still the eventlisteners executed only once.

can you help us how to do this?

Comment: This may cause a memory leak, you are registering a new event listener on every mouseover event. And you also have hardcoded values, when the event occurs you just set them and their results is the same.

Comment: how can we implement the A to B motion in javascript

Comment: why do you need to add and event listener to `re3` every single time you place your mouse on top of `re2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the mousemove event instead of the mouseover event. This will allow you to continuously update the position of the element as the mouse moves

```
const re21 = document.getElementById("reso");
let isMoving = false;

re21.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  if (!isMoving) {
    isMoving = true;
    re21.style.position = "absolute";
    re21.style.top = `${event.clientY}px`;
    re21.style.left = `${event.clientX}px`;
  }
});

re21.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  isMoving = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to initialise a counter on an outer scope than your event callback function, then you increment it every time you trigger the event.

```js
const elm = document.getElementById("reso");

let initialTopPosition = 0;
let initialLeftPosition = 0;


function moveElement() {
  initialTopPosition++;
  initialLeftPosition++;

  elm.style.top = `${initialTopPosition}%`;
  elm.style.left = `${initialLeftPosition}%`;
  console.log("Exiting Listener- mouseOver");
};

elm.addEventListener("mousemove", moveElement);
```

```css
#reso {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="reso"></div>
```

Comment: just a minor issue. Don't forget to add - -onmouseover="myFunction()" - - to your div. Without this, it might not work on your computer.

Comment: No, that's discouraged now. [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) should do the trick

Comment: Didn't work on my Safari not sure why. Not until I added onmouseover to the div